# Load external script that uses modules

Tags: javascript, require

I am trying to create a javascript library that I can include anywhere (not just on my site). It will have dependencies but I don't want the end user to have to include them all. How do I do this?

NOTE: I've googled far and wide and can't get an answer other than using RequireJS or such as a declared dependency.

An example library using require but I don't need to include dependencies. https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js/blob/master/dist/oauth.js

Any user can just include the script and go.

Comment: You include your dependencies listed in package.json or bower.json. any user wanting to add your library will rather run one of those

Comment: @amenadiel that's what I figured. Just didn't know if there was a way around it. Thank you for your help.